# Is it possible to lazily initialize a property and assert it?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, kotlin, assert, lazy-initialization

How can I lazy init a field and execute an assert on it?

I tried

```
val table: Array<FormatInfo> by lazy {
   val t = arrayOf(...)
   assert(table.size == FORMAT_COUNT, { System.err.println("GLI error: format descriptor list doesn't match number of supported formats") })
   t
}
```

But it goes in overflow:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at gli.GliKt$table$2.invoke(gli.kt:451)
    at gli.GliKt$table$2.invoke(gli.kt)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131)
    at gli.GliKt.getTable(gli.kt)
    at gli.GliKt$table$2.invoke(gli.kt:693)
    at gli.GliKt$table$2.invoke(gli.kt)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131)
    at gli.GliKt.getTable(gli.kt)
    at gli.GliKt$table$2.invoke(gli.kt:693)...
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Btw, I think this is called `property`, not `field`

Comment: Don't hide the code that causes the exception. Don't make us guess what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace looks like you are calling the property from inside the `lazy {}` lambda, which obviously makes it crush.

This should work:

```
val table: Array<FormatInfo> by lazy {
   val t = arrayOf(...)
   myAssert(t)
   t
}
```

Comment: Crap, I missed that, thanks! Btw is this the right way to lazily init a `property` and assert it or is there a better way?

Comment: Looking on your example I can't really understand why you are making this property lazy at all. I would go with a normal property.

Comment: If you do want to apply stuff (e.g. asserts) to something returned in a lambda I recommend using `apply` instead of a temp variable. e.g.: `val table: Array<FormatInfo> by lazy { arrayOf(...).apply { assert(this...) } }`.